# Flutter/Dart DateTime max min value

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I want to know the [`DateTime`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) min and max value for comparison.

> DateTimes can represent time values that are at a distance of at most 100,000,000 days from epoch (1970-01-01 UTC): -271821-04-20 to 275760-09-13.

I see no min/max define in `DateTime`, is there any way to programmatically get the min/max values?

```
DateTime min;  // -271821-04-20  
DateTime max;  // 275760-09-13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw some one define min/max in this post:

https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/796

```
    // DateTimes can represent time values that are at a distance of at most 100,000,000
    // days from epoch (1970-01-01 UTC): -271821-04-20 to 275760-09-13.
    static DateTime minDateTime = DateTime.utc(-271821,04,20);
    static DateTime maxDateTime = DateTime.utc(275760,09,13);
```

Comment: This raises an `ArgumentError` if passed to `showDatePicker` as `firstDate` and `lastDate`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like this is something that is available at the moment. You could make a feature request and see what happens, but the only thing right now is to just make getters for the max and min values. Unfortunately, we can't make static extension methods either, so you'll just have to use a static class or globals:

```dart
class DateTimeMaxMin {
  static const _numDays = 100000000;
  
  static DateTime get min => DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(0).subtract(Duration(days: _numDays));
  static DateTime get max => DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(0).add(Duration(days: _numDays));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `firstDate` of `showDateRangePicker`, the minDateTime seems like `DateTime.utc(-271820, 12, 31)`